# how to match a string from excel in web page using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the string from the excel sheet and want to check whether the string is present in web page or not. This is the code i'm trying,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "driver path");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(url);

        String ps = driver.getPageSource();
        File src = new File("excel path\\Data.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet Sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row = Sheet1.getRow(0);

        for(int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++) {
        if(ps.contains()) {

            System.out.println("TEXT is present");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("TEXT is not present");
        }
        }

    }

}
```

But it was not working, Can any one help me in this pls...

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this before your if condition.

```
String strtext=row.getcell(i).getStringCellValue()
Your modified code looks like:
for(int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++) {
String strtext=row.getcell(i).getStringCellValue();//ensure your cell type is text.
//then your if condition
if(ps.contains(strtext)){
```